# Using the nd3 package with hyperref

Tags: logic

I just came across the rather useful [`nd3`](https://phloxgroup.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/nd-manual2.pdf) package. However, it seems not to work correctly with the `hyperref` package since it redefines the `\ref` command. Without `hyperref` this package is pretty useless in a professional document, at least for me. Does anybody know of any fix to make the two work?

A simple MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}


\usepackage{ND}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\noindent ${(P \to Q), \Big((\neg Q) \lor R\Big), (R \iff S)} \vdash (P \to S)$

\begin{ND}[Proof][proof][][][.8\linewidth]
    \ndl{}{$P \to Q$}{Premise} \label{PimpliesQ}
    \ndl{}{$(\neg Q) \lor R$}{Premise} \label{notQorR}
    \ndl{}{$R \iff S$}{Premise} \label{RiffS}
    \ndl{}{\textcolor{red}{$(R \to S) \land (S \to R)$}}{\ref{RiffS}, $\iff$, Equivalence} \label{RimppliesSandSimpliesR}
\end{ND}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it `nd3` or `ND`? I don't find a `nd.sty` or `nd3.sty` or `ND.sty` file in my up-to-date `TL 2017` distribution. `texdoc nd` provides a LaTeX tutorial in French language, so this seems not related to a package of the same name

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Assuming the OP is interested in Lemmon-style natural deduction proofs, the LaTeX package file `nd3.sty` -- which contains the statement `\ProvidesPackage{ND}` along with an environment called `ND` and a macro called `\ndl` -- may be obtained from  [here](http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/nd3.sty). For sure, the `nd3` package redefines both `\label` and `\ref`, which all but guarantees that it'll be incompatible with both `hyperref` and `cleveref`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Mico is correct. In case it is not obvious I have also provided a link to the package in my post. And yes the problem is exactly what he has pointed out.

Comment: @Mico: Tell that the O.P ;-) He is responsible of providing the link to non-standard packages

Comment: @KG - Just to clarify: The link you provided is to a version of the package's user guide, not to the style file.

Comment: @KG - Short of performing a serious rewrite of various portions of the `nd3` package, I can't see a clear path towards undoing the changes that the package makes to `\label` and `\ref`. Asking for such a rewrite would amount to making a feature request. However, feature requests are off-topic for this site. You may want to see if you can contact the package's author and inquire if he might be willing to modify the package to restore some kind of compatibility with the `hyperref` and `cleveref` cross-referencing packages.

Comment: @Mico I was afraid of that. The package has not been actively maintained since 2010 and I can't find any alternative. Are you aware of any?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author? I have packages I haven't touched in years, but I'd look at them again if somebody reported a problem. In LaTeX terms, hasn't been touched doesn't necessarily mean hasn't been and isn't maintained. Maintenance can be quite an idle occupation if nobody asks for anything ....

Comment: This doesn't compile even without `hyperref`.